# Delete items from state array and add this items another state array

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I'm want Delete items from state array and add this items another state array

```
deleteItem = (id) => {
this.setState(prevState => {
  const index = this.state.productData.findIndex(item => item.id === id); this.state.storeData[0].saveProducts.push(this.state.productData.slice(index, 1))
  return this.state.productData
 })
 }
```

Json StoreData , Saveproducts item of object in array

```
[ 
  { 
  "code": "f1", 
  "name": "storage-no-1", 
  "capacity": 125, 
  "temperture": -18,
  "humidity": 3 ,
  "saveProdoucts":[]
  }, 
 { 
  "code": "f2",
 "name": "storage-no-2",
 "capacity": 15, 
 "temperture": -18,
 "humidity": 25,
 "saveProdoucts":[]
  },
  {
   "code": "R3",
   "name": "storage-no-3", 
    "capacity": 40, 
    "temperture": 21,
    "humidity": 30,
     "saveProdoucts":[]
  } 
 ]
```

Comment: Don't mutate state.

Comment: productData is an array consist of items you want to filter the array with the id , then remaining items should be saved in the storeData[o].saveProducts array . Is that what you are looking for

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS i have a product list, i want add product list to store component whit A series validate : example a=a b=b c=c .. is Ok then add to Store

Comment: @Dani i didnt get you can you explain it

Comment: @Dani basically you are trying remove the item from product and add to the saveProducts array in the storedData

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS yes,i want this

Comment: @Dani thanks for the response will post the answer and let you know

Comment: @Dani added the soltion with the sample code , paste the code in react app and try to run it. Please check and let me know if it resolved for you

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS JsonData Added in Question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

please check the below sample code, on click of each item it will remove the item from the productData and add the corresponding item in the saveProducts property of the storedData.

I hope this will solve the issue. Please save the code in react local development and try to run it.

```js
import React, { Component, Fragment } from 'react';

class App extends Component {

  state = {
    productData: [
      { id: 1, productName: "test 1" },
      { id: 2, productName: "test 2" },
      { id: 3, productName: "test 3" },
      { id: 4, productName: "test 4" }
    ],
    storedData: [{ saveProducts: [] }]
  }

  addItem = (id) => {
    const { productData } = this.state
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      productData: productData.filter(product => product.id !== id),
      storedData: [
        {
          saveProducts: [
            ...prevState.storedData[0].saveProducts,
            ...productData.filter(product => product.id === id)
          ]
        }
      ]
    })
    )
  }

  render() {
    // Destructuring 
    const { productData, storedData } = this.state
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <ul>
          {productData.map(product => {
            return (
              <li
                onClick={() => this.addItem(product.id)}
                key={product.id}>
                <p>{product.productName}</p>
              </li>
            )
          })}
        </ul>
        <h2>
          Saved Products
        </h2>
        {
          storedData[0].saveProducts.length > 0 ?
            storedData[0].saveProducts.map(product => {
              return (
                <p key={product.id}>
                  {product.productName}
                </p>
              )
            })
            :
            "No Products Selected"
        }
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187109/discussion-on-answer-by-dileep-thomas-delete-items-from-state-array-and-add-this).

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS email id: amirradnia8@gmail.com

Comment: @DILEEP THOMAS please send message to email and i,m send project

Comment: @Dani please check your inbox